# Getting all the values matching a key pattern from redis through Lua

Tags: python, regex, lua, redis

I am trying to find all the keys and their values matching a specific pattern using py-redis and lua and here is my code

```
rc = redis.Redis(..)

rc.set('google:',100)
rc.set('google:3',200)
rc.set('google:2',3400)
rc.set('google',200)
rc.set('fb',300)


get_script = """
local value = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
return value
"""
get_values = rc.register_script(get_script)

print get_values(rc.keys(pattern='google:*'))

print get_values(keys=['google:'])
print get_values(keys=['google:*'])
```

The output that I am getting is

```
100
100
None
```

First of all I do not get why I am getting None for the last print statement. My original purpose is to get all the keys ( and their values) matching the pattern but I am only getting the first key

Comment: perhaps it takes a regex. try `google:.*`

Comment: This gives me the following error ResponseError: @user_script: 2: Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I have found what I was missing

Instead of GET I should have passed KEYS as first argument of the initial redis.call and then iterate over the keys to get the values

```
get_script = """
local keys = (redis.call('keys', ARGV[1]))
local values={}  

for i,key in ipairs(keys) do 
    local val = redis.call('GET', key)
    values[i]=val
    i=i+1
end

return values
"""
get_values = rc.register_script(get_script)

print get_values(args=['google:*'])
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, **however** - using `KEYS` is probably the worst thing you can do with Redis. IMO the OP needs to rethink his approach.

Comment: Look at SCAN, which is designed for searching/matching keys: http://redis.io/commands/scan

Comment: You would be more useful if you can demonstrate how to use scan to solve his problem